# Problem when deleting specifics nodes in linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, delete-operator

I am trying to delete specifics nodes by a give data in my `pop` method, so my linked list code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
private:
public:
    int n1;
    int n2;
    Node *next;

    Node(int n1, int n2)
    {
        this->n1 = n1;
        this->n2 = n2;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
public:
    Node *start;
    int size;
    LinkedList()
    {
        this->start = NULL;
        this->size = 0;
    }

    void append(int n1, int n2)
    {
        Node *node = new Node(n1, n2);
        if (this->start == NULL)
        {
            this->start = node;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *temp = this->start;
            while (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = node;
        }
        this->size++;
    }

    void print()
    {
        Node *temp = this->start;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << "n1: " + to_string(temp->n1) + ", n2: " + to_string(temp->n2) + "\n";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void pop(int n1, int n2)
    {
        Node *temp = this->start;
        Node *prev = NULL;

        if (temp != NULL && temp->n1 == n1 && temp->n2 == n2)
        {
            this->start = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            this->size--;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            while (temp != NULL && temp->n1 != n1 && temp->n2 != n2)
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                return;
            }
            prev->next = temp->next;
            this->size--;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
};
```

And then I was testing with different code in `main` method, so for example with the next `main` code I am tryng to delete the node that has `(0, 0)` data:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    LinkedList lk;
    lk.append(0, 0);
    lk.append(0, 1);
    lk.append(0, 2);
    lk.append(0, 3);
    lk.append(0, 5);
    lk.append(0, 6);

    lk.pop(0, 0);

    lk.print();

    return 0;
}
```

And with the above code my output is successful because `(0, 0)` is not in the linked list:

```
n1: 0, n2: 1
n1: 0, n2: 2
n1: 0, n2: 3
n1: 0, n2: 5
n1: 0, n2: 6
```

But with the next `main` code, I am tryng to delete intermediate nodes, last node, first node:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    LinkedList lk;
    lk.append(0, 0);
    lk.append(0, 1);
    lk.append(0, 2);
    lk.append(0, 3);
    lk.append(0, 5);
    lk.append(0, 6);

    lk.pop(0, 5);
    lk.pop(0, 1);
    lk.pop(0, 0);
    lk.pop(0, 6);

    lk.print();

    return 0;
}
```

And with the above `main` code my output is nothing. It is only a message error:

```
[Done] exited with code=3221225477 in 1.173 seconds
```

Meanwhile my expected output should be:

```
n1: 0, n2: 2
n2: 0, n2: 3
```

Testing with different main codes, I notice that my problem is in `pop` method, but I don´t really know how to fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: *"I notice that my problem is in `pop` method,"* -- this is progress. Can you get the exact line? If you don't have a debugger, you might have to rely on diagnostic messages streamed to `std::cerr` (an unbuffered output stream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
while (temp != NULL && temp->n1 != n1 && temp->n2 != n2)
```

Should be

```
while (temp != NULL && (temp->n1 != n1 || temp->n2 != n2))
```

Otherwise, it will delete first element that matches either n1 or n2, but not necessarily both.

While we are here, let's simplify your `pop()` function:

```
    void pop(int n1, int n2)
    {
        Node *temp = start;
        Node *prev = NULL;

        while ( temp != NULL && ((temp->n1 != n1) || (temp->n2 != n2)) )
        {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (prev == NULL)
            {
               start = temp->next;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = temp->next;
            }
            size--;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why don´t you use `this`? If I am used to use `this` can I use it in this method?

Comment: @asker - There are many opinions on this. But for the most part, my team will prefix our private member variables of the class with underscore (e.g. `_size` and `_start`) and use variable names for local variables (e.g. `temp` and `prev`) without underscores.  That way it's very obvious in code when we are accessing a member variable vs a local variable without having to explicitly use `this->`.  There's nothing technically wrong with `this->`. It's just not the usual convention.